# Read the filename from a folder that contains just one file

Tags: php

I have folders that have one file in each.

I am trying to read the name of that file and pass to variable in php.

```
foreach(glob('photos/folder_name/thumbs') as $filename)
{echo $filename;}
```

Using the above script, no data is returned for $filename. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: You need `glob('/photos/folder_name/thumbs/*')`. glob is intended for wildcard matches, and you don't have any wildcards, so the only thing that path will match is the directory itself. If you get NOTHING back at all, then that path doesn't exist to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wildcards in the string you give to glob.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```